# What is the property for automatic html form validation?

Tags: javascript

When a submit type button is clicked, if input is invalid, it prompts another input (eg. not filling required forms). However, if input is valid, it does something else, what is the property that determines which route it goes.

Comment: Are you referring on how to execute a logic after your inputs are valid?

Comment: Yes, I would like to know the property determining whether its valid and use it to execute something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach an event called `submit` to the form element that will execute a callback (function) when all the inputs are valid.

HTML:

```
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
  <input id="username" type="text" required placeholder="Username">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input id="email" type="email" required placeholder="Email">
  </div>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
const form = document.querySelector('form')

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  // This function will only get executed when there's no input errors or all inputs are valid.
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log('Form submitted without errors!')
})
```

Link:
https://codepen.io/fenwil/pen/NWGPePJ?editors=1011

Comment: Thank you. After jostling with form is null for half an hour it turns out the solution is to put the script tag at the end.